# Get {"error":"404 Not Found"} when uploading pypi package to gitlab with twine

Tags: upload, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pypi, twine

I am following the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/index.html) while trying to upload my pypi package to gitlab private repository using twine.

I am working on a community project on gitlab.com that is set to private.

I am using the following commandline:

```
twine upload dist/*.tar.gz --skip-existing --verbose --repository-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/mygroup/myproject/packages/pypi
```

When I run this command, twine asks for username and password. I enter my email and 2-factor token (I have 2-factor authentication enabled for my gitlab.com account)

```
Enter your username: my@email.com
/home/myname/.venv/myproject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twine/auth.py:72: UserWarning: No recommended backend was available. Install a recommended 3rd party backend package; or, install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See https://pypi.org/project/keyring for details.
  warnings.warn(str(exc))

Enter your password:
```

Then I get a pleasant message:

```
Uploading myproject-0.0.1.tar.gz
100%|██████████████████| 25.6k/25.6k [00:00<00:00, 87.4kB/s]
```

Followed by a less pleasant error message:

```
Content received from server:
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
HTTPError: 404 Not Found from https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/mygroup/myproject/packages/pypi
Not Found
```

At this stage I have a few comments.

1. Documentation mentions a [repository of example gitlab-ci.yaml files](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates) but there is no mention of PyPi or twine in in any of the examples that I could find there.
2. Documentation mentions gitlab.example.com. I don't know why, will this work for gitlab.com as well?

Anyway, I don't know how to proceed from here. I have limited ways of debugging this or interpreting the meaning of the resulting error. **How can I make this work**?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you have to use the project id in the repository-url:

```
twine upload dist/*.tar.gz --skip-existing --verbose --repository-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/pypi
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is part of CI then better use gitlab variables:

```
twine upload dist/*.tar.gz --skip-existing --verbose --repository-url 
 ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi
```

This will properly take package_id and api url